# UTF-8 support on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, serial, file

I want to run a python program that receives the data through serial communication and saves it to a file, but after receiving the data this error shows up. Any idea? (code runs ok in Windows but in Raspbian OS I have this error)(the data is in JSON format)

error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):  File
> "/home/pi/Desktop/ReadFromPort.py", line 11, in    line =
> ser.readline().decode("utf-8") UnicodeDecoderError: 'utf-8' codec
> can't decode byte 0xbd in position 2: invalid start byte

Python code:

```
from serial import *
from serial.tools import list_ports
import os

ser = Serial('/dev/ttyS0',115200, timeout = 1)


with open("output1.txt","w",encoding="utf-8") as file:
    while True:
        line = ser.readline().decode("utf-8")
        if(line != ""):
            #print(line)
            file.write(line)
            file.flush()
            os.fsync(file)
```

Comment: what happens if you remove the `.decode("utf-8")`?

Comment: @jsotola  file.write(line)
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes

Comment: Not Pi specific. This is a general coding question.

Comment: @Milliways My problem is on Pi. no problem in windows :)

Comment: UTF-8 is the native encoding in RpiOS.  The problem here is your input is either not UTF-8 or the data is getting corrupted.

Answer (score 3):

File is not in utf8 format, so the decoder is seeing an invalid (i.e., non-utf8) byte sequence. 0xbd is the ½ character in Latin-1, utf8 represents it as the two-byte sequence \xc2\xbd

Comment: so what is the solution to this problem do you think?

Comment: You need to debug the serial communication, maybe there's a baud rate mismatch or some interference causing invalid characters to be received. Alternatively the sending device is sending stuff you're not expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Type of `ser.readline()` is `bytes`.

`bytes.decode(encoding='utf-8')` return a `str` if and only if there is not a UnicodeError risen. It is this in fact that appens in your line

```
line=ser.readline().decode('utf-8')
```

So, you must give a good value to the `encoding` parameter.

You'll find the different encoding  [here](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings). If it is a latin-1 (*for instance*), you must have the following code :

```
with open("output1.txt","w",encoding="utf-8") as file:
while True:
    line = ser.readline().decode("latin-1")
    if(line != ""):
        #print(line)
        file.write(line)
        file.flush()
        os.fsync(file)
```

To improve code quality, you can take avantage of catching exceptions ;)

Comment: thanks, but the data have some Persian character, so i should use utf-8 i guess.

Comment: Might help if you indicated *where* the data is from  because chances are your problem is it *isn't* in UTF-8.  How do you know it contains Persian characters?

Comment: @goldilocks My Raspberry Pi zero (Raspian OS) which has a python program receives the JSON data (indicates Persian character) through serial communication (GPIO-UART) from Raspberry Pi 4 (8 gig ram model) (Windows 10 IoT Enterprise - C# app)

Comment: Well, UTF-8 *isn't* the native format used by Windows, it's UTF-16, although I am sure it is not that either (since they are 100% incompatible, ie., it would be wrong from the first byte or two).  So you might try and confirm whether it is supposed to be utf-8, or something else.